# How can I get the UITextView to scroll only when it's full of text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, textview

I have this `UITextView` that works great except, I can't get the text inside the `UITextView` to start scrolling only after the `UITextView`'s size in nearly full, the UITextView is 4 lines tall, but as soon as I reach the 2nd line the 1st line is pushed up, I don't want the view to begin scrolling until I've reached the 5 line. `scrollingEnabled = NO` keeps it from scrolling at all, so that didn't work.

```
UITextView *barf_ = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 310.0, 155, 50)];

barf_.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

//[barf_ scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([barf_.text length], 0)];

barf_.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;

barf_.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;

barf_.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
```

Answer (score 2):

When your UITextView is loaded set scrollEnabled to NO. Then set the text view's delegate to `self` or some other object and implement the UITextViewDelegate method

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

This method will get called anytime the user makes a change to the text inside the view. Inside this method you need to figure out how big your text is and if it goes beyond the bounds of the text view. If so you enable scrolling. Use this method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

This is a UIKit category method on NSString. It returns a CGSize that will tell you the height of whatever text string you call it on. In your case it would be something like

```
CGSize textSize = [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font
                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
if (textSize.height > textView.frame.size.height) {
    textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
} else {
    textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, as others with similar problems have mention, with a small textView, **it automatically adds 32 padding to the bottom.**

A simple fix is to add `YourTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);` inside `shouldChangeTextInRange` method, that fixed my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `contentInset` may help the text to appear more correctly within the `UITextView`. However, it won't help solve the issue whereby the `UITextView` has scrolling enabled despite not having more text to view.

Similarly, methods such as `sizeWithFont` have limitations. As explained in Mike Weller's excellent blog series [iOS Development: You're Doing It Wrong](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com), `NSString` isn't a good object to ask regarding how large a `UIView` should be. Many `UIView` subclasses such as `UILabel`, `UIButton`, etc. have insets and other considerations that must be accounted for during sizing. `UITextLabel` is no exception.

Mike Weller's particular entry on this subject is:

[You're Doing It Wrong #2: Sizing labels with -[NSString sizeWithFont:...]](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html)

iOS 7 promises us more sophisticated text handling in `UITextView`, with properties such as `textContainerInset`. But what to do in the meantime?

Well, first we know that `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. Therefore, the golden rule that if the `contentSize` is larger than the view's `bounds` property, the scroll view will scroll so we can see more content.

Checking out `contentSize` agains the `bounds` won't work either because we know that `UIScrollView` is already calculating whether it should scroll or not based on the text, and it's giving us the wrong answer.

This is where arbitrary adjustment values come to the rescue! For me this value was `17.f`. For you - depending on your fonts - it maybe different. We then take control and decide whether we should allow the scroll view to scroll:

```
static const CGFloat kArbritaryHeight = 17.f;
CGFloat adjustedContentHeight = myTextView.contentSize.height - kArbritaryHeight;
CGFloat boundsHeight = CGRectGetHeight(myTextView.bounds);
BOOL tooMuchContent = adjustedContentHeight > boundsHeight;

if (tooMuchContent)
{
    myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
else
{
    myTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method to check whether your string will actually render larger than your text view and see if you need to enable scrolling. You will have to call it any time the text in your scrollview is set, however.

ex:

```
CGSize barfStringSize = [barfString sizeWithFont:[barf_ font] 
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(barf_.bounds.size.width, MAXFLOAT) 
                                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]
[barf_ setScrollEnabled:barfStringSize.height > barf_.bounds.size.height]
```